# Relativity and Bell's inequalities

Tags: relativity, bells-inequality, locality

I am reading [a collection of interviews](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521457289) taken with prominent physicists as in an aftermath of famous Alain Aspect [experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_test_experiments). Between them John Bell states that if local realism has to go, he would be inclined to ditch locality, betting that there is something wrong with relativity.

I understand that relativity is truly one of the foundations of modern physics including QFT and that Lorenz transformations are tested to a great level of accuracy.

My question is, if somebody is actively working on this, as an alternative to the relativity theory ?

P.S. I mean a real alternative, not reintroducing some kind of ether/preferred reference frame which can never be detected.

Comment: The true solution (as Bell himself acknowledged) is to accept determinism - such philosophy is not so much a problem for physics as it is for physicists. Bell's Theorem basically rests on the assumption that the workings of the universe are *unsystematic* (i.e. not subject to cause, effect, and conservation, an assumption that is really quite contrary to scientific investigation and much physical theory and philosophy). If we accept that the universe *is* systematic, then the problem of Bell's Theorem is solved by making it irrelevant.

Comment: Incidentally, I often think the apparent problem of "entanglement" in QM is simply due to a fundamental misunderstanding of what is going on.

Comment: Note that even if locality is ditched information itself cannot travel faster than light.  So Relativity remains valid. Note that the problem with the Bell results of no local realism could also mean that both locality and realism (or at least naive realism) may not hold. It's pretty clear from QT that determinism or some common versions of realism cannot be true, and from the it also and the AdS/CFT correspondence that locality also is probably not true. But both Relativity and QT can still be. It's interpretation, not physics that you are discussing.

Comment: @BobBee, I don't agree that any theory requires that determinism cannot be true, because *any* useful theoretical conclusion *requires* some sort of determinism. A non-deterministic system cannot be modelled at all, because it has no rules (even statistically or probabilistically, because there would be no guarantee that the statistical process applied at one moment would hold valid in the next, once you reject that stastistical effects have underlying causes). Correspondingly, the use of statistics or probabilities does not imply non-determinism - on the contrary, it affirms determinism.

Comment: QT theory is not like a classical probability. In fact the wavefunction evolution is deterministic (from the Shrodinger and equivalent equations, also called unitary evolution), and that conserves the probability total to 1 always. But the results, measurements or even where anything is at any one time is indeed quantum probabilistic. Bell found that. The probabilities do not go by classical probability theory, and that the real value of his theorem/findings. TRy finding a good review, it'll blow your mind and take away false interpretations.

Comment: Anyway, you are totally off the mainstream: the mainstream does not believe that physics or the universe is deterministic in your sense.

Comment: @BobBee, I disagree. All physicists believe in some sort of determinism in order to do their work, and some mainstream physicists are willing to admit it - indeed, the inability to agree on the interpretation of quantum mechanics is itself "mainstream physics". Even Bell did not rule out determinism - he simply asserted in a just-so fashion that he felt it "unlikely". And like I say, this (I suppose it could be called...) probabilism is not incompatible with determinism - it *requires* determinism.

Comment: Well, we can disagree to disagree. Most mainstream physics understand that there is something uniquely quantum probabilistic that is happening, but certainly also that the macroscopic world is of course deterministic in the sense of cause and effect. QM and QFT is of course unitary evolution so the wavefunction evolution is deterministic, just not the result of any one microscopic observation. That Shrodinger's can be dead or alive, and is in a superposition of the two, is part of the mainstream. I won't further argue, you may disagree but it is irrelevant